# Python: Divide two columns, a/b, if b is 0 -> assign 0

Tags: python, pandas

I need to make new column in df (apples per pupils) divide two columns (apples and pupils), and if the number of pupils is 0, I should just assign zero to that row.

Current values:

| apples | pupils |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 5 | 0 |

Expected output:

| apples | pupils | avg_apples_per_pupils |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 2.5 |
| 6 | 3 | 2.0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0.0 |

I tried using this:

```
if df[df['pupils']!=0]:
    df['avg_apples_per_pupils'] = df['apples'] / df['pupils']
else:
    df['avg_apples_per_pupils'] = df.assign(avg_apples_per_pupils='0')
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'm completely open for other approaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['avg_apples_per_pupils'] = (df['apples'].div(df['pupils'])
                               .mask(df['pupils'].eq(0), 0)
                               )
```

Or [`numpy.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html):

```
df['avg_apples_per_pupils'] = np.divide(df['apples'], df['pupils'],
                                        where=df['pupils'].ne(0))
```

Output:

```
   apples  pupils  avg_apples_per_pupils
0       5       2                    2.5
1       6       3                    2.0
2       5       0                    0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.where` condition:

```
df['avg_apples_per_pupils'] = np.where(df['pupils'].ne(0), df['apples'] / df['pupils'], df['pupils'])
```

---

```
   apples  pupils  avg_apples_per_pupils
0       5       2                    2.5
1       6       3                    2.0
2       5       0                    0.0
```